# didBeginContact not called : this instance is unique to me

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So, I am still experimenting with Sprite Kit for my first time ever, and I would like to test for collision. So, I searched around a bit in Apple's documentation, around Stack Overflow, online tutorials, and other forums. However, I was unable to find something a tip or *code* that makes what I am doing work. So, here are the relevant pieces of code:

This is the code for an obstacle:

```
func createObstacle(){

    var ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 20)
    var width = UInt32(self.frame.width)
    var random_number = arc4random_uniform(width)
    ball.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(random_number), frame.height+20)
    ball.strokeColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    ball.glowWidth = 1.0
    ball.fillColor = SKColor.darkGrayColor()
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
    ball.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 6
    ball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    self.addChild(ball)
}
```

This is relevant code for the thing that it would collide with:

```
    let circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 20)
    circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
    circle.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()
    circle.strokeColor = SKColor.blueColor()
    circle.glowWidth = 1.0
    circle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 4
    circle.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    circle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
```

And this is the code for contact:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody!
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody!

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB

    }
    else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == 4 && secondBody.categoryBitMask == 6) || (firstBody.categoryBitMask == 6 && secondBody.categoryBitMask == 4)){

        println("HI")
    }else{println("NO")}

}
```

Sadly, nothing is being printed at all, so something's wrong. Any idea why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Your class should have delegate `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
```

In `didMoveToView` write this:

```
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

**EDIT**

Define `CategoryBitMask` like this

```
struct PhysicsCategory {

    static let circleCategory   : UInt32 = 0b1       // 1
    static let ballCategory     : UInt32 = 0b10      // 2
}
```

Give `CategoryBitMask` to circle and ball

```
circle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.circleCategory
ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ballCategory
```

Then check contact like this:

```
(func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == 0b1 && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == 0b10 ) || ( contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == 0b1 && contact.BodyB.categoryBitMask == 0b1 ))
        println("Contact")
    }
}
```

> Sorry for typos didnt used editor

Comment: @IHaveAQuestion Then i think there is problem in your didBeginContact Try if it is working by just writing simple PRINT without any IFs (check if that method is called). CHECK EDIT !

Comment: The didBeginContact() function is never being called at all

Comment: @IHaveAQuestion You are making some mistakes i suggest you to check this tutorial and do it all from begining.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/84434/sprite-kit-swift-tutorial-beginners